# Getting no valid constructor error during serialization in Java

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink

I am triying to serialize my class RowSerializable in order to use it in a DataSet but i'm getting this error

"Could not read the user code wrapper: es.foo.flink.Utils.RowSerializable; no valid constructor"

```
public class RowSerializable extends Row implements Serializable {

   private Object[] fields2;

   public RowSerializable(int arity){
       super(arity);
       this.fields2 = new Object[arity];
   }
   public RowSerializable(){
       super(0);
   }
}
```

At first i didn't have the non-arg constructor created so i did it, but i'm still having the same error

Comment: Build clean and test it again. Also, whatever you're storing in `fields2` **must** *also* be `Serializable`.

Comment: i rebuild it and nothing changes. And im storing generic types in fields2 as integers or strings

Comment: It is the base class `Row` that needs an accessible no-args constructor, or whatever the nearest non-seriazable base class is. If you're using standard Java Serialization, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the people, who would need the reference. As EJP clearly stated, we need to add no-args constructor for the POJO class which we wish to serialize with custom Serializer.

Here a [Sample POJO class - Record.java](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/mastering-flink/blob/master/chapter10/flink-batch-adv/src/main/java/com/demo/flink/batch/Record.java)

Here is a [Sample Custom Serializer Class - RecordSerializer.java](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/mastering-flink/blob/master/chapter10/flink-batch-adv/src/main/java/com/demo/flink/batch/RecordSerializer.java)

To use the above POJO and Custom Serializer, we need to register these with execution environment.

Following is a sample code for that

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(Record.class, RecordSerializer.class);
```

Here is a link to the complete [code](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/mastering-flink/tree/master/chapter10/flink-batch-adv).